# Log4j : How to disable custom log level

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using `log4j 1.2` with `xml` configuration. I am having a custom level named `EVENT`. How can I disable the logs in this level?

```
public class STSLevel extends Level
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 3491141966387921975L;
    public static final int EVENT_INT = 90000;
    public static final Level EVENT = new STSLevel(90000, "EVENT", 0);
    protected STSLevel(int arg0, String arg1, int arg2)
    {
            super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
    public static Level toLevel(String sArg)
    {              
            if ((sArg != null) && (sArg.toUpperCase().equals("EVENT"))) {
                    return EVENT;
            }

            return toLevel(sArg, Level.DEBUG);
    }
    public static Level toLevel(int val)
    {
            if (val == 90000) {
                    return EVENT;
            }

            return toLevel(val, Level.DEBUG);
    }
    public static Level toLevel(int val, Level defaultLevel)
    {              
            if (val == 90000) {
                    return EVENT;
            }              
            return Level.toLevel(val, defaultLevel);
    }
    public static Level toLevel(String sArg, Level defaultLevel)
    {              
            if ((sArg != null) && (sArg.toUpperCase().equals("EVENT"))) {
                    return EVENT;
            }               
            return Level.toLevel(sArg, defaultLevel);
    }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you place the code of your custom level 'EVENT'?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan I have pasted the class.

Comment: Do you have anyother level greater than this one i.e. > 90000. Set that one in rootLogger level will ignore logs from this level.